# Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to connect the database, but i'm getting the issue like Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost'. Can anybody help me to fix the issue ?

```
Your connection attempt failed for user 'xxx' from your host to server at localhost:3306:
  Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost'

Please:
1 Check that mysql is running on server localhost
2 Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
3 Check the xxx has rights to connect to localhost from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines) 
4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for localhost connecting from the host address you're connecting from
```

Comment: please check username and password on your db.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create user xxx@localhost

```
Create user 'xxx'@'localhost' identified by password 

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'xxx'@'localhost'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I already tried this mysql command, still i'm facing the same issue.

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO   'xxx'@'localhost'

Comment: Other than these commands, Is there any way to overcome from this issue?